# .net core DI, use value from one dependency to register another dependency

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm using .net core 2.1 and have a situation where I am registering a service with the native IoC container and need a value from that to register another set of services

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => 
    {
        services
        .AddSingleton<IFirstService, FirstService>()
        .AddMyServices(FirstService.MyProperty);
    });
```

Where `AddMySerivces` is an extenstion of `IServiceCollection` which I use to register some other dependencies like so

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(
    this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string myProperty)
{
    // user myProperty here to register other things
}
```

What's a good way to get that `FirstService.MyProperty` passed into `AddMyServices`

Comment: Does `FirstService.MyProperty` determine what subsequent services are registered?

Comment: No, it's just a parameter for that second one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISomeService>(sp =>
    {
        var firstService = sp.GetRequiredService<IFirstService>() as FirstService;
        var firstProperty = firstService.FirstProperty;

        // Build an instance of ISomeService based on the property
    });
}
```

This registers a factory for a dependency where it depends on the first service.
Of course you'd need to do this for each service :/

You can also add your property to your IFirstService interface so you don't need to cast the service.

Comment: Hey, this looks good. How do I use this if it's a `DbContext` being added instead of an `ISomeService` (`serviceCollection.AddDbContext<TContext>()`).

Comment: Hmm... you might have to re-implement AddDbContext in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your registered service from IServiceCollection like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IFirstService, FirstService>();

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var firstService = serviceProvider.GetService<IFirstService>();
    // now pass firstService to AddMyServices method or get that directly in it
}
```

Comment: Be very careful with this, as this creates a new 'container' with its unique cache. This could easily lead to "Torn Lifestyles". This means that you get multiple instances of a `Singleton` registration, which can lead to weird bugs.

Comment: Do not do this unless you can guarantee that BuildServiceProvider will be called only once. I would only do this if using the ServiceCollection manually without the HostBuilder.